# Thread exit in a dll which was run time dynamically linked

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, dll

I have a dll in which I have a class in whose constructor I launch a std::thread. The std::thread is joined to in the destructor of the class.
An object of this class can be created either directly or using a exported GetObject method.

In my application when I do a load time linking to the dll and create a static object of the class in the dll (outside main), the thread is terminated correctly. Initialisation done outside main like this:

```
static Threader thr;
```

However if I do a run time linking to the dll and create the object via the GetObject method, this time wrapped inside a static object (again outside main). The thread is terminated before the object is destroyed. Initialisation done outside main like this:

```
Threader * thread = nullptr;
struct Setup
{
    Setup()
    {
        HINSTANCE threader = LoadLibrary(L"ThreadInDll.dll");

        typedef Threader& (*PFUN)(void);
        PFUN th = (PFUN)GetProcAddress(threader, "GetObject");
        thread = th ? &((*th)()) : nullptr;
    }
};
static Setup firstThing;
```

I am on windows using VS2015.

I am observing thread termination in the output window by printing the thread id of the thread launched inside the dll and then comparing the 
***"The thread xxxx has exited with code 0 (0x0)"*** messages in the output window.

Also in the dll object destructor, I am able to join to the thread even after it has got terminated in the above case.

**P.S :** What I am trying to do might appear convoluted, however the description here is a simplified version of my exact use case. So please bear with me on that front.

Comment: you are going to have to use a wrapper method that can call the dll threader function. In your wrapper method you would catch the exceptions from the thread.

Comment: @dgsomerton : I am not having any exceptions in the thread (as I am just sleeping in the thread, not really doing anything 'exceptional'). I think the OS is terminating it explicitly. I am not sure why.

Comment: are you sleeping in a loop ? what happens when the sleep expires, does it continue and exit the thread ?

Comment: Yes. It wakes up, completes the thread and cleans up properly in my code. However in the output window I see a thread exited message(with the same thread id) before all of this happens.